# Zebra stripes lose position when filtering dynamically and using jquery :even

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

**Or, how to re-set header rows to 'even' while within the same table?**

After a fair bit of googling, I've got zebra striping working fairly well using a snippet I found in this forum.  My challenge now is to get the striping 'count' to reset after a category heading - so that the first stripe after each heading is white. I added thead and tbody tags thinking that might help target more effectively but not sure where to go from here. Any suggestions?

Here is the fiddle if that helps: http://jsfiddle.net/9MnWr/8/

HTML

```
<select>
    <option value="fruit" selected>All</option>
    <option value="discount">Discount</option>
    <option value="premium">Premium</option>
    <option value="apple">Apples</option>
    <option value="orange">Oranges</option>
</select>

<table>

    <thead> 
        <tr class="orange fruit heading discount"><th>Florida Oranges</th></tr>
    </thead>

    <tbody>
        <tr class="orange fruit discount"><td>discount orange</td></tr>
    </tbody>

    <thead>
        <tr class="apple fruit heading discount"><th>Niagara Apples</th></tr>
    </thead>

    <tbody>
        <tr class="apple fruit discount"><td>discount apple</td></tr>
    </tbody>

    <thead> 
        <tr class="orange fruit heading discount premium"><th>California Oranges</th></tr>
    </thead>

    <tbody>
        <tr class="orange fruit discount"><td>discount orange</td></tr>
        <tr class="orange fruit"><td>orange</td></tr>
        <tr class="orange fruit premium"><td>premium orange</td></tr>
    </tbody>

    <thead> 
        <tr class="apple fruit heading premium"><th>Thornberry Apples</th></tr>
    </thead>

    <tbody>
        <tr class="apple fruit premium"><td>premium apple</td></tr>
        <tr class="apple fruit"><td>apple</td></tr>
    </tbody>

    <thead> 
        <tr class="orange fruit discount heading"><th>Italian Oranges</th></tr>
    </thead>

    <tbody>
        <tr class="orange fruit"><td>orange</td></tr>
        <tr class="orange fruit"><td>orange</td></tr>
        <tr class="orange fruit discount"><td>discount orange</td></tr>
    </tbody>

</table>
```

jQuery

```
$(function () {

            $( 'tr:even' ).css( "background-color", "#eee" );
            $('select').change(function () {
            $('tr').hide();
            $('.' + $(this).val()).show();
            $( 'tr:even' ).css( "background-color", "#eee" );
        });
    });
```

Comment: Just don't use jQuery for that, but CSS3 selectors.

Comment: If you need it backwards-compatible, just re-apply the jQuery zebra function after filtering (and any other manipulation to the DOM)

Comment: Why JS when you can do it with CSS? `tbody tr:nth-child(even) {
   background-color: #eee;
}`

Answer (score 0):

Why not just use the nth-child(even) CSS selector? Otherwise, just make sure that any functions that mutate the table call your jQuery implementation again (resetting the classes on the rows first, of course).

Comment: I tried that before but it didn't survive 'mutation' in that the table contains several sections, and the first line of each section needs to reset to even.